# How do I programm a textarea in HTML where people can change their own fonts etc.?

Tags: html, input, textarea

I mean for example when you write an e-mail in Gmail, the user can select his own fonts and font sizes. How do I make that with HTML or with any other programming language that is supported by a webbrowser?

Comment: This is much too broad for a good answer. Break your question down into focussed, answerable parts and post new questions as you need to.

Comment: In what programming language should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ckeditor.com/

Or google for

wysiwyg html

this stands for what you see is what you get.